# Distribution of a certain stochastic process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Consider on a probability space $(\Omega, \cal F, \mathbb P)$ the following stochastic process on $[0, \infty]$, where $W(t)$ is a Wiener process, all the coefficients $\lambda(t), \mu(t)$ and $\sigma(t)$ are adapted to the filtration generated by the Wiener process:

$$
dX(t) = (\lambda(t) - \mu(t))X(t) dt + \sigma(t)X(t)dW(t).
$$

Question: what is the distribution of $X(t)$, for $t >0$?

I have tried to adapt the method which is generally used to show the log-normality of the distribution of a Geometric Brownian Motion (when the coefficients are not just nonrandom, but constants), but I didn't go very far; evidently the method for constant coefficients cannot be generalized here. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: did you look at the associated martingale problem?

Comment: Not really. How should I do?

Comment: I'm just learning this material for the first time, so this might be the blind leading the blind, but hopefully this helps: http://stats.lse.ac.uk/cetin/files/MP.pdf  Solving the martingale problem is supposed to give an easier way to solve the SDE in some (all?) cases, since the Martingale Problem version doesn't have a stochastic integral term

Comment: Thank you for the comment, me too I don't know much of this. Do you know how to apply that method in this case? The problem is that although this SDE is not difficult to solve, I cannot see how to figure out the distribution of the solution.

Comment: What is the solution of the SDE? I'll see if I can help